# add click function to retrieve related data from object in web api

Tags: arrays, json, asp.net-web-api

this is my starter work 
I just call the web API and retrieved the hotel names

```js
(function() {
  var myAPI = "https://gmgapi.azurewebsites.net/SystemParameters/Hotels/GetAll?langId=en";
  $.getJSON(myAPI, {
      format: "json"
    })
    .done(function(data) {
      doSomething(data);
      console.log("Load was performed.");
    });
})();

function doSomething(data) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var div = $("<div>");
    var label = $("<label>").text(data[i].DisplayValue);
    $(div).append(label);
    $('#result').append(div);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"> </div>
```

now i want to click on hotel name to get other data related to hotel like deescription and other data

the proplem faced me that i couldn't get the value correctely when i clicked on html to retrive the data

i tried to declare var and use it but not worked for me like showed here

```js
     (function () {
            var myAPI = "http://gmgapi.azurewebsites.net/SystemParameters/Hotels/GetAll?langId=en";
            $.getJSON(myAPI, {
                format: "json"
            })
              .done(function (data) {
                  doSomething(data);
                  doSomethinginClick(data);
              });
        })();

        function doSomething(data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var div = $("<div>");


                var h1 = $("<h1>").text("  Hotel name : " + data[i].DisplayValue);

             
                $(div).append(h1);
                $('#result').append(div);
            }
        }

        function doSomethinginClick(data) {
          //  var clicked = data[this].Id;
                      var clicked = data[0];


            $('h1').click(function () {
                var divx = $("<div>");


                var h1 = $("<h1>").text("  Hotel name : " + clicked.DisplayValue);

                var p = $("<p>").text("   Hotel Description : " + clicked.DisplayValueDesc);

                var p2 = $("<p>").text(" CurrencyTitle : " + clicked.CurrencyTitle);

                var price = $("<p>").text(" PriceStart : " + clicked.PriceStart);

                var rate = $("<p>").text(" Rate : " + clicked.Rate);
               
                $(divx).append(h1, p, p2, price, rate);
                $('#resultsec').append(div);


            });
         
        }
```

```html
    <div id="result">

    </div>
    <div id="resultsec">

    </div>
    

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of, In the method `doSomethinginClick()`, where you define the h1 click function, you have missed to define the div element which you are appending to.

Add the following

```
var div = $("<div>");
```

To make the solution more dynamic, you can store a identifier on the h1 tag thats connect the tag to an hotel.
I added a custom field called hotelId on the html tag for this

```
function doSomething(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var h1 = $("<h1></h1>").text("  Hotel name : " + data[i].DisplayValue);
        h1.data('hotelId', i);
        $("#result").append(h1);
    }
}

function doSomethinginClick(data) {

    $('h1').click(function () {

        var id = $(this).data('hotelId');
        var clicked = data[id];

        var h1 = $("<p>").text("  Hotel name : " + clicked.DisplayValue);

        var p = $("<p>").text("   Hotel Description : " + clicked.DisplayValueDesc);

        var p2 = $("<p>").text(" CurrencyTitle : " + clicked.CurrencyTitle);

        var price = $("<p>").text(" PriceStart : " + clicked.PriceStart);

        var rate = $("<p>").text(" Rate : " + clicked.Rate);

        var div = $("<div>");
        $(div).append(h1, p, p2, price, rate);
        $('#resultsec').append(div);


    });
 }
```

Here's a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/16ZPgwh3lfvHmrR2RWnQ?p=preview) with mocked data

Comment: thanks for your reply.
the problem face me that i have many hotels name generated from first function 
and I need when click on any of them get the related data as i have an array of objects loaded at API

Comment: if you try my first snippet , it retrieve more than one hotel name these are object on array , i need to define on click to load all other related data

Comment: @user4833581 updated my answer with danymic fetch of hotel data when clicking